# Is there any way to check the encoding of scripts for Pull Request review in Github?

Tags: git, github, encoding, character-encoding, pull-request

Where I work, the database scripts need to be encoded in ANSI to work, we constantly miss a file that is encoded in UTF-8 and this can create a lot of problems, so to avoid this, each file is checked manually by someone else.

**The question**: is there any way to automatically check (or convert) the encoding of scripts before approving pull requests on github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Github Actions

GitHub has a feature called [Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) that you could leverage, if available in your repository. This allows you to do a server-side hook to do various checks. You can add a build hook to check the encoding of scripts.

https://github.com/2DegreesInvesting/resources/issues/53 has one such example (edited to hopefully fit your use case):

```
name: CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - name: run the checkout action
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: list the directory
        run: echo '! find $GITHUB_WORKSPACE -type f -exec file --mime {} \; | grep -v "charset=binary$" | grep -v "charset=us-ascii$"' | bash
```

#### Git Hooks

Another way to help this is to tell developers to install a client-side commit/push hook what does the same thing. You can read more about them here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

#### Build Process Integration

Lastly, if your company has a build pipeline, you can add a custom build step to detect this. This check would be after the change is pushed, but would hopefully catch the bug before it reaches production.

Comment: Man, thank you very much, these solutions look promising.